# Tails -> Verify the ISO image -> Using the command line: "gpg: Impossible de v'erifier la signature : No public key"

Tags: tails, tor-install, verification

I follow this [Tails docs](https://tails.boum.org/install/download/openpgp/index.en.html#command-line):

```
$ brew install gpg    

$ gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verify tails-amd64-3.0.iso.sig tails-amd64-3.0.iso
gpg: Signature faite le Sat Jun 10 17:37:05 2017 CEST
gpg:                avec la clef RSA A5091F72C746BA6B163D1C183C83DCB52F699C56
gpg: Impossible de v'erifier la signature : No public key

$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --keyid-format 0xlong --verify tails-amd64-3.0.iso.sig tails-amd64-3.0.iso
gpg: Signature faite le Sat Jun 10 17:37:05 2017 CEST
gpg:                avec la clef RSA A5091F72C746BA6B163D1C183C83DCB52F699C56
gpg: Impossible de v'erifier la signature : No public key

$ pwd
/Users/fyodor/Downloads/tails-amd64-3.0
```

Do I miss something or docs not complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. This isn't the correct installation method for you to follow.

   > These instructions are for people who are **already familiar with basic usage of OpenPGP**
2. You're not following the instructions at all.

   > 3. If you are doing the verification for the first time, **download the [Tails signing key](https://tails.boum.org/tails-signing.key) and import it in your keyring.** If you are working from Tails, the signing key is already included.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the "No public key" error if you have imported an old version of the Tails signing key.

> gpg --check-sigs A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F

```
pub   4096R/58ACD84F 2015-01-18 [expired: 2017-01-11]
uid       [ expired] Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2015-01-18  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!         BE2CD9C1 2015-01-19  Tails developers (signing key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
uid       [ expired] Tails developers <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
```

The Tails signing key I imported last time expired on 2017-01-11.

After I downloaded the new signing key the result is different:

> gpg --check-sigs A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F

```
pub   4096R/58ACD84F 2015-01-18 [expires: 2018-01-11]
uid       [ unknown] Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2015-01-18  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!         BE2CD9C1 2015-01-19  Tails developers (signing key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
uid       [ unknown] Tails developers <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        58ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sub   4096R/752A3DB6 2015-01-18 [expires: 2018-01-11]
sig!         58ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!         58ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sub   4096R/2F699C56 2015-01-18 [expires: 2018-01-11]
sig!         58ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!         58ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sub   4096R/A0EDAA41 2016-08-30 [expires: 2018-01-11]
sig!         58ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
```

The new key expires in 2018-01-11. Now when I verify the signature I see "Good signature".